# Renaming all dataframe columns with stringr and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I am trying to rename all columns in my data frame using `dplyr` and `stringr`, but it seems not to be working the way I desire. How should I change the following code to get the output I want (shown in the code below)?

Here is the fully reproducible code:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
library(rlang)

# dataframe
x <-
  tibble::as.tibble(cbind(
    Grace_neu_wrong = c(1:4),
    Grace_acc_wrong = c(1:4),
    Grace_att_wrong = c(1:4),
    Grace_int_wrong = c(1:4)
  ))

# defining custom function to rename the entire dataframe in a certain way
string_conversion <- function(df, ...) {
  
  # preparing the dataframe
  df <- dplyr::select(.data = df,
                      !!rlang::quo(...))
  
  # custom function to split the name of each column in a certain way
  splitfn <- function(x) {
    x <- as.character(x)
    split <- stringr::str_split(string = x, pattern = "_")[[1]]
    paste(split[2], split[3], '_', split[1], sep = '')
  }
  
  # applying the splitfn function to each column name and outputting the data frame
  df_new <- df %>%
    dplyr::select_all(.funs = colnames) %>%
    dplyr::mutate_all(.funs = splitfn)
  
  return(df_new)
  
}

# the output I get
string_conversion(df = x, names(x))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   Grace_neu_wrong Grace_acc_wrong Grace_att_wrong Grace_int_wrong
#>   <chr>           <chr>           <chr>           <chr>          
#> 1 NANA_1          NANA_1          NANA_1          NANA_1         
#> 2 NANA_1          NANA_1          NANA_1          NANA_1         
#> 3 NANA_1          NANA_1          NANA_1          NANA_1         
#> 4 NANA_1          NANA_1          NANA_1          NANA_1

# the output I desire
tibble::as.tibble(cbind(
  neuwrong_Grace = c(1:4),
  accwrong_Grace = c(1:4),
  attwrong_Grace = c(1:4),
  intwrong_Grace = c(1:4)
))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   neuwrong_Grace accwrong_Grace attwrong_Grace intwrong_Grace
#>            <int>          <int>          <int>          <int>
#> 1              1              1              1              1
#> 2              2              2              2              2
#> 3              3              3              3              3
#> 4              4              4              4              4
```

Created on 2018-02-08 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.1.1.9000).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this in a single line without using mutate, which should be for the column values rather than the column names. Instead, do the following using `stringr::str_replace` and regular expressions.

1. The pattern `"(.*)_(.*)_(.*)"` is three groups of characters separated by underscores.
2. We simply make the replacement `"\\2\\3_\\1"`, which is group 2, then group 3, then an underscore, then group 1, giving us the desired result.

The code is consequently just one line long:

```
names(x) <- str_replace(names(x), "(.*)_(.*)_(.*)", "\\2\\3_\\1")
print(x)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  neuwrong_Grace accwrong_Grace attwrong_Grace intwrong_Grace
           <int>          <int>          <int>          <int>
1              1              1              1              1
2              2              2              2              2
3              3              3              3              3
4              4              4              4              4
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Very elegant solution.